# Building capicxx-someip-runtime for Android using NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, embedded-linux

I am trying to build the `capicxx-someip-runtime` using the Android NDK version r17b. I have successfully built its dependencies using the same NDK. The `capicxx-someip-runtime` is an open source GENIVI IPC framework whose git repo URL is given below.

Capicxx-someip-runtime git repo
[Link](https://github.com/GENIVI/capicxx-someip-runtime.git)

It's a cmake based project. The cmake configuration command that I used is

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/hari/projects/jlr-rse/downloads/android-ndk-r17b/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=27 ../ -DCommonAPI_DIR=/home/hari/projects/jlr-rse/capicxx-core-runtime/build/install/lib/cmake/CommonAPI-3.1.12 -Dvsomeip_DIR=/home/hari/projects/jlr-rse/vsomeip/build/install/usr/local/lib/cmake/vsomeip -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=/home/hari/projects/jlr-rse/boost_1_65_1/install/lib -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(pwd)/install
```

After solving some initial compilation issues by including missed out header files, I am stuck up now with the following compilation issue whose log is shown in below URL

Compilation error log
[Link](https://gist.github.com/gehariprasath/fa41f0919d0a06bd759c59b0bfdd98ae)

I did some research on this and I understand that Android c++ libraries don't support semaphores. But this particular compilation issue is just about `EFD_SEMAPHORE` being reported as an undeclared identifier. Android c++ libraries do seem to have support for 'eventfd' because otherwise the error thrown would have been different. Is my understanding correct here?

Comment: If you need Common API on Android, you probably will find the [d-bus binding](https://github.com/GENIVI/capicxx-dbus-runtime) easier.

Comment: @AlexCohn Primarily we will be using Common API to communicate with external entities over Network. So we have decided to go with vsomeip as the binding mechanism.